# Rails serialize heir class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, inheritance, serialization, attributes

How can I specify that I want to serialize additional attributes of classes that inherit from an abstract one ?
(I am using ActiveModel::Serializer)

EDIT : I have associations/references that I need to keep in my serializer, not just attributes

```
class AbstractClass
    [attributes]
    **has_one :reference** # Added after Edit
end

class Foo < AbstractClass
    field :some_special_foo_field
end

class Bar < AbstractClass
    field :some_other_bar_field
end

Class Baz
   has_many :abstract_class
end
```

I want a JSON that would look like

```
{:baz => [
    { id => "foo_1_ID",
      some_special_foo_field => "something"
    }, {
      id => "bar_1_ID,
      some_other_bar_field => "Somewhere"
}]
```

Somewhere in my controller I am doing:

```
@bazz = Baz.all
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @bazz}
end

class BazSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes [what I need]
    has_many :constraints, serializer: AbstractClassShortSerializer, embed: :objects
end

class AbstractClassSerializer
    **has_one :reference, serializer: SomethingSerializer, embed: :objects** # Added after Edit
    attributes :[attributes I want to keep]
end
```

Now Problem : depending on whether the objects in @bazz are Foo or Bar, I'd like to have their special attributes in my JSON, but I currently can't with this code

This question is somewhat linked to this one [Simulating constraints and sub-constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522767/rails-simulating-constraints-and-sub-constraints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple:

- do one serializer for foos and one serializer for bars
- dont use `has_many` in your `baz` serializer

Do this way:

```
class AbstractClassShortSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes common_attributes_here
end

class BarSerializer < AbstractClassShortSerializer

end

class BazSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes [what I need]
  attributes :constraints

  def constraints
    object.constraints.map do |constraint|
      if constraint.foo?
        FooSerializer
      elsif constraint.baz?
        BazSerializer
      else
        AbstractClassShortSerializer
      end.new(constraint, scope: scope).attributes
    end
  end
```

end

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know I could use this trick. 

But I still feel like it could be done in a shorter way. Here the problem is that I need a specific `AbstractClassShortSerializer`. 

Somewhere else in my app, I am using the default rails serializer for `AbstractClass` and it already outputs the specific foo&bar attributes in the JSON.

Comment: you can also do it by overriding `attributes` in the serializer, but its less clear

Comment: Well the problem is that if later in my code I add additional classes that inherit from AbstractClass, I'll have to change this serializer everytime.

Comment: well it means each time you have a different subtype it will require its own serializer, which doesnt sound absurd

Comment: Yes but is there a way to pick the default serialiser by default? Something like `else {constraint.class.default_serializer}` ?

Comment: up to you to implement foo? or replace those lines

Comment: Ouch. I just realised that doing 
`c = AbstractClass.first` and then `c.class` would return `Bar` or `Baz` and not just `AbstractClass` ^^"

Comment: So basically I can just split the attributes and only keep those that belong to the right class ? Something like `constraint.class.attributes.strip(AbstractClass.attributes)` (I'll need to read some doc to reach the correct syntax)

Comment: I dont understand what you cant do

Comment: Well basically in your answer, you are creating a new Serializer from each constraint, then you grab its attributes.
But I also need to grab its associations. I tried looking at the doc, and I believe I need somehting like merge_associations() but there is no explanation in the doc.
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/josevalim/active_model_serializers/ActiveModel/Serializer#merge_association-instance_method

Comment: Sorry I meant `include_association()`. But I'm not sure it does what I think anyways. I'm gonna try to use `serializable_hash`.